# Ruby - Transpose Matrix without using extra space - Not altering my original array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, matrix, transpose

I am trying to solve a challenge: to *transpose* a nested array without using the pre-defined `transpose` method or using any "extra space" like temporary variables.

Input: `[[1,2,3], [7,6,5], [8,2,1]]`
Output: `[[1,7,8],[2,6,2],[3,5,1]]`

Here is the algorithm:
 We just have to swap the indexes. 
for example:

```
  (0,0) -> (0,0)
  (0,1) -> (1,0) and (1,0) -> (0,1)
  (0,2) -> (2,0) and (2,0) -> (0,2)
```

and it goes on.

Below is my code

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [7,6,5], [8,2,1]]

arr.each_with_index do |inner, i|
  inner.each_with_index do |e, j|
    arr[i][j], arr[j][i] = arr[j][i], arr[i][j]
  end
end

arr
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [7, 6, 5], [8, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: I could not get the term "extra space". Do you want to print array in string format without using space in it?

Comment: This is not possible. Everything you do in Ruby, will be done with method calls. And every method call allocates a stack frame. Therefore, it is impossible to do *anything* in Ruby without using any extra space.

Comment: By extra space I mean not initializing another array or using any temp variables. The iterators are fine.

Comment: "not initializing another array" – But in your code, you do just that: `arr[i][j], arr[j][i] = arr[j][i], arr[i][j]` creates a new array for the parallel assignment. "[not] using any temp variables" – So, if I do `foo.bar.baz` that is allowed because it doesn't use temporary variables, but if I do `temp = foo.bar; temp.baz` that is not allowed because it uses a temporary variable, even though both snippets have the *exact same* semantics, use the *exact same* amount of space, and will even (for any halfway decent compiler) compile to the *exact same* code? That is ridiculous.

Comment: I've deleted my answer and voted to close because I can't figure out what the question is. The crux of the problem is the OP's inability to explain what "without using any extra space" means.  That is clearly impossible, especially in light of the requirement given in the title (which I just noticed) that the given array is not to be mutated.

Comment: "By extra space I mean not initializing another array or using any temp variables. The iterators are fine." - but why?

Comment: you could use [[1,2,3], [7,6,5], [8,2,1]].transpose

Comment: @Kris: Especially since the OP *does* actually initialize another array, namely the temporary one created by the parallel assignment.

Comment: You selected an answer that modifies the original array, despite the requirement in the title that it not be altered. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap two numbers via addition and subtraction:

```
a = 2
b = 10

a = a + b #=> 12
b = a - b #=> 2
a = a - b #=> 10

a #=> 10
b #=> 2
```

With this algorithm we can transpose the nested array using only the existing array elements:

```
arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [7, 6, 5],
  [8, 2, 1]
]

(0...arr.size).each do |i|
  (i+1...arr.size).each do |j|
    arr[j][i] = arr[j][i] + arr[i][j]
    arr[i][j] = arr[j][i] - arr[i][j]
    arr[j][i] = arr[j][i] - arr[i][j]
  end
end

arr
#=> [
#     [1, 7, 8],
#     [2, 6, 2],
#     [3, 5, 1]
#   ]
```